# Use java scanner at cmd

Tags: java, cmd, java.util.scanner

How to read data from cmd using

i used this method and it works fine until it arrive to user input and the debugger get into hasnext and hang

```
public String readCMD() {
    try {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String ch ;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            ch = sc.next();
            System.out.print(ch);
            sb.append(ch);

        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: when calling hasnext() it waiting for text input

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public String readCMD() {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String ch;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            ch = sc.next();
            System.out.print(ch);
            sb.append(ch);

        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nextLine()`:

```
while (!(ch = sc.nextLine()).equals("")) {
     System.out.print(ch);
     sb.append(ch);
}
```

This way you read in a loop until you read an empty string...

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out the loop using some condition, here below if user enter "exit" as input then it will break out:

```
public String readCMD() {
    try {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String ch ;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            ch = sc.next();
            System.out.print(ch);
            sb.append(ch);
            if(ch.equals("exit")) {
              break;
            }

        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: the code stops at has next before the user input an thing

Comment: what do you mean by stop? the program will wait for the next input string from user until user enter "exit"

Comment: the problem that is a login porcess and user name and password  is automatically inserted from a file